# Indexing R dataframes, by boolean

Tags: r

Suppose we have a data frame

```
a[1:3,2:3]
AWAY HOME
1        CLE       BOS
2        MIL       CHI
3        POR       LAL
```

If I do

```
a[1:3,2:3]==c("CLE","BOS")
AWAY HOME
1      TRUE      TRUE
2     FALSE     FALSE
3     FALSE     FALSE
```

I get as expected. Yet if I do

```
a[,2:3]==c("CLE","BOS")
AWAY HOME
1       TRUE     FALSE
2      FALSE     FALSE
3      FALSE     FALSE
....(Others left out, as unimportant)....
```

Why is this so? Shouldn't it give the same answer, with the exception that the other executes on the entire dataframe? Where does this difference come from? Shouldn't both cases return TRUE TRUE as the first line?

Comment: `==` works on a single element you need `%in%` on a loop i.e. `lapply(a[2:3], '%in%' , c("CLE", "BOS"))`

Comment: Recycling.  See `help("==")`

Comment: Would you be so kind as to post an answer with a simple example?

Comment: I will accept the answer, as soon as it lets me. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `%in%` instead of `==` as is for comparing a single element

```
a[1:2] <- lapply(a[1:2], '%in%' , c("CLE", "BOS"))
a
#   AWAY  HOME
#1  TRUE  TRUE
#2 FALSE FALSE
#3 FALSE FALSE
```

Sometimes, `==` works as we expect, but it is just due to chance because it does the comparison by columns, i.e. in the 'AWAY' column, it compares the first element with "CLE", second with "BOS", third  with "CLE", fourth with "BOS" (due to recycling).  This requires some kind of ordering of the elements to get the output correct, while `%in%` checks whether those elements are there.